# Karma Tracking Reports: Should use redis-only or redis-mysql hybrid?

Tags: mysql, redis

Background: I'm building a web-app that consists of a tool and an accompanying reporting system to track the total usage of the tool. I want to show the user reports based on daily usage, monthly usage, yearly usage and total usage, all in terms of minutes. Think minutes of usage = "karma" points.

I'm planning on implementing this usage tracking in redis. Now I could

1)  increment multiple counters at the same time(Daily, Monthly,Yearly).

Or

2) I could just keep 2 sets of records:

- a) Total Karma (simple Redis counter)
- b) A Row in MySql with the Karma and the Date and use SQL queries to generate the reports for annual Karma and monthly Karma.

The advantage of example b) is that it won't clutter up Redis with a whole lot of denormalized data. But that might not be a disadvantage IF its trivial to port this data to MySQL when need be.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use redis as a primary data store.  However, keep the following in mind:

1. Your working set should fit in memory.  Otherwise it becomes a mess.
2. You'll need to back up your redis data regularly and treat it just as important as a MySQL backup.

If you see your redis data growing larger than a single instance, I suggest looking at [presharding](http://antirez.com/post/redis-presharding.html).